# The import org.omg cannot be resolved

Tags: java, eclipse, plugins, corba

I'm following [this tutorial](http://www.ejbtutorial.com/corba/tutorial-for-corba-hello-world-using-java) on how to set up corba, but I can't use the packages they are talking about, and no where on the internet can give an adequate explanation of how to get them.

I want the following imports to not give me an error.

```
import org.omg.CosNaming.*;
import org.omg.CosNaming.NamingContextPackage.*;
import org.omg.CORBA.*;
import org.omg.PortableServer.*;
import org.omg.PortableServer.POA;
```

Downloading [JacORB](https://www.jacorb.org/download.html) just gives me a github file the also has imports of the package 'org.omg'

Somebody said [use this findjar site](https://www.findjar.com/jar/com.oracle/oc4j/11/jars/orbacus.4.3.1.jar.html?all=true), I have no idea what the things are on that site

Comment: 'Help > Install new software' and the Eclipse marketplace are for plug-ins that are installed as part of Eclipse. The project you link to doesn't appear to be an Eclipse plug-in so you can't 'install' it. This is just something you would have as a project in your workspace.

Comment: https://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/technotes/guides/idl/tutorial/GSapp.html Here's an example that requires it, I just need stuff with the org.omg.........

Comment: And that jacorb plugin is just something I read somewhere that someone said I should used, I can't seem to find anything on how to install the actual org.omg..... packages that I need to include in my imports

Comment: did you try: 
Help > Install New Software... 
In the "Work with" section, click the Add... button
Click Local and select the directory you unzipped, then click OK. Its path appears in the "Location" field. Leave the "Name" field empty.

Comment: Yeah I get Could not file file://Users/.......
I just feel like I'm using some 3rd party variation with installing this and just want the original org.omg... that all these examples are referencing but which none of them say what it is. I just feel like it shouldn't be that hard to find a package that all these examples like that one I posted 3 comments ago just use and don't explain

Comment: I don't even think that git file has it. 
I just want org.omg packages. I think it just contains files that have the line `import org.omg.....` which is my original problem

Answer (score 8, accepted):

Be sure to download the CORBA API from a reliable source:

- [Glassfish](https://mvnrepository.com/artifact/org.glassfish.corba/glassfish-corba-omgapi/4.2.3)
- [JOnAS](https://repo1.maven.org/maven2/org/ow2/jonas/osgi/corba-api/5.0.1/corba-api-5.0.1.jar)

Add a folder to your project called lib and drag the jar file into lib

Right Click the jar file and select Build Path -> Add to Build Path

Then go to project -> properties -> libraries and move the jar to your CLASSPATH

Comment: If the above links don't work, [I downloaded it from here](http://www.java2s.com/Code/Jar/c/Downloadcorbaapi501jar.htm)

Comment: yes, it worked with me, just copy the dependency tag stand paste it in your pom.xml file. and then update your project.